# Timer leading to locks

Tags: delphi, timer, delphi-xe8, locks

Can anyone tell me why this code is leading to my application to stop responding.

My application calls a COM library.  I wait for the COM library events to fire so that I can carry on.
I use a timer to keep checking if the COM library fired:

```
procedure MyTimer(hWnd: HWND; uMsg: Integer; idEvent: Integer; dwTime:   Integer); stdcall;
begin
  //writeln('Timer Event');
end;
```

I keep checking if the event fired this way:

```
procedure MyClass.Loop(bwait: boolean);
var
s: TDateTime;
id: uint;
begin
  try
    id := SetTimer(0, 1, 1000, @MyTimer);
    s := Now;
    while bwait do
    begin
      sleep(30);
      Application.ProcessMessages;
      if bwait = false then // Event fired, all good=> exit
      begin
        KillTimer(0, id);
        break;
      end;

      if Now - s > EncodeTime(0, 0, 1000, 0) then // Timed out=> exit
      begin
        KillTimer(0, id);
        break;  
      end;
    end;

  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end;
```

When the COM library event fires it sets the bwait boolean variable to true which means all good and we can exit and carry on.

If event hasn't fired within a certain time then I exit & inform user.

This code sometimes creates thread locks.

My application and the COM library stop responding.
What's causing the lock ?

How can the above code be improved ?

Thank you.

Comment: Without more knowledge of the COM library, threading models, etc. it is hard to say. Certainly the code in the question looks very dubious indeed, starting with the calls to `Sleep` and `Application.ProcessMessages`.

Comment: I'm not using threads in my application.
The COM library might using threads internally but I don't know.  
Don't I need Application.ProcessMessages to check if my bwait variable has been set by the COM library event ?
I will try the code without the sleep & Application.ProcessMessages.
Thanks

Comment: Don't try to write synchronous code using an asynchronous model. The whole point of using events is that you're ***supposed to*** continue doing whatever else you please; and then handle the event when it fires. Trying to undo that throws all the benefit away and forces you to block your code until you receive some particular event... And what happens if you don't receive it? _Things lock up!_

Answer (score 2):

The whole purpose of events is to NOT write synchronous blocking code.

`Application.ProcessMessages()` is not intended to process COM messages.  You can use `TEvent` instead, which has a `UseCOMWait` parameter to make the `TEvent.WaitFor()` method use `CoWaitForMultipleHandles()` internally to process the COM message loop while waiting for the event to be signaled.

```
uses
  ..., DateUtils, SyncObjs;

type
  MyClass = class
  private
    doneEvent: TEvent;
    procedure COMEventHandler(parameters);
    procedure Loop(bWait: Boolean);
    ...
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure DoIt;
  end;

constructor MyClass.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  ...
  doneEvent := TEvent.Create(True);
end;

destructor MyClass.Destroy;
begin
  ...
  doneEvent.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure MyClass.COMEventHandler(parameters);
begin
  doneEvent.SetEvent;
end;

procedure MyClass.Loop(bWait: Boolean);
var
  s: TDateTime;
begin
  if not bWait then Exit;
  try
    s := Now;

    repeat
      case doneEvent.WaitFor(30) of
        wrSignaled: begin
          // Event fired, all good=> exit
          Break;
        end;
        wrTimeout: begin
          if MillisecondsBetween(Now, s) > (1000 * 1000) then
          begin
            // Timed out=> exit
            Break;  
          end;
          if GetQueueStatus(QS_ALLINPUT) <> 0 then
            Application.ProcessMessages;
        end;
        wrError: begin
          RaiseLastOSError(doneEvent.LastError);
        end;
      end;
    until False;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end;

procedure MyClass.DoIt;
begin
  doneEvent.ResetEvent;
  // invoke COM function that will eventually trigger the COM event...
  Loop(True); // wait for event to fire or timer to elapse...
  ...
end;
```

But this is not the correct way to write event-driven code.  Like any asynchronous system, you should break up your code into smaller pieces and let the events notify your code when to invoke those pieces.  Don't write blocking code at all.  For example:

```
const
  APPWM_COM_EVENT_DONE = WM_APP + 1;
  APPWM_COM_EVENT_TIMEOUT = WM_APP + 2;

type
  MyClass = class
  private
    MsgWnd: HWND;
    procedure COMEventHandler(parameters);
    procedure WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure DoIt;
  end;

constructor MyClass.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  MsgWnd := AllocateHWnd(WndProc);
end

destructor MyClass.Destroy;
begin
  KillTimer(MsgWnd, 1);
  DeallocateHWnd(MsgWnd);
  inherited;
end;

procedure MyClass.COMEventHandler(parameters);
begin
  KillTimer(MsgWnd, 1);
  PostMessage(MsgWnd, APPWM_COM_EVENT_DONE, 0, 0);
end;

procedure MyTimer(hWnd: HWND; uMsg: UINT; idEvent: UINT_PTR; dwTime:   DWORD); stdcall;
begin
  KillTimer(hWnd, idEvent);
  PostMessage(hWnd, APPWM_COM_EVENT_TIMEOUT, 0, 0);
end;

procedure MyClass.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  case Message.Msg of
    APPWM_COM_EVENT_DONE:
    begin
      // Event fired, all good
    end;

    APPWM_COM_EVENT_TIMEOUT:
    begin
      // Event timed out
    end;

  else
    begin
      Message.Result := DefWindowProc(MsgWnd, Message.Msg, Message.WParam, Message.LParam);
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure MyClass.DoIt;
begin
  SetTimer(MsgWnd, 1, 1000 * 1000, @MyTimer);
  // invoke COM function that will eventually trigger the COM event...
  // exit now, let WndProc() handle the notifications later...
end;
```

Comment: I'm interested in your 2nd solution but can't get it to work as I want.  
I'm doing the following:
SetTimer(MsgWnd, 1, 1000 * 1000, @MyTimer);
Invoke code which will trigger my event
While true do
begin
  if event fired or timedOut then
    exit;
end

It seems that the While-do loop stops the event from firing. Any suggestion around this problem ?
Thank you.

Comment: @Walid get rid of the `while` loop and just exit immediately after invoking the COM code. The loop doesn't belong. That was the whole point of the 2nd example, to not use any loops at all

Comment: @Remy_Lebeau
How do I guarantee that event fires or timesOut before DoIt() exited ?
Event fires successfully everytime but after DoIt has exited.

This is what I want to achieve:
1)SetTimer; 
2)Invoke code which triggers event
3)If event fires then we're good to go to next step\ If timedOut then inform user 

Thank you.

Comment: Read your & Craig's comments. It looks that I need something else as I need to wait for event to fire or timeout.
The 1st example seems to block event from firing.  Any suggestion ?  Thank you.

Comment: @Walid "*How do I guarantee that event fires or timesOut before DoIt() exited ?*" - it is *supposed* to exit before the events are fired, that is the whole point of the 2nd example. Letting `DoIt()` exit allows control to return to the main message loop, thus keeping the UI responsive and COM working in the background until the COM event is fired or the timer elapses. If you need to make `DoIt()` wait for the event/timeout before exiting, then you are right back to the original problem, and are thus required to run a secondary message loop, like in my 1st example

Comment: Loop in the 1st example seems to be preventing loop from firing.  Any solution around this problem ?   Thank you.

Comment: @Walid the 1st example works fine for me. If it doesn't work for you, you are probably not using it correctly. What is the COM threading model of the COM object you are invoking? What COM threading model are you initializing the calling thread as?